# Adding and removing values of input checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The script that I have written (admittedly with help) allows a user to select checkboxes and it will add the value of the selected box to an input, separated by a comma.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var variable = 1
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var element = $(".test.hidden").clone(true);
    var testInputs = element.find(".testInputs").click(clickHandler);


    testInputs.attr("unique-index", variable);
    var target = element.find('.user_input2 #insert');
    target.attr("unique-identifier", variable)
    element.removeClass("hidden").appendTo(".paste:last");
    variable += 1;

  });

  function clickHandler() {
    console.log($(this).attr('unique-index'));
    const index = $(this).attr('unique-index')
    const targetsValue = $(`#insert[unique-identifier="${index}"]`).val();
    console.log('sup', targetsValue)
    const combo = targetsValue ? `${targetsValue}, ${$(this).val()}` : $(this).val()
    $(`#insert[unique-identifier="${index}"]`).attr('value', combo);
  }


  $(".test").keyup(function() {
    var test;
    console.log('sup')
    if ($(".test").is(":checked")) {

      test = $(".test").val();
    };

    $("#insert").val(test);

  });

  $("#testbtn").click(function() {
    $(".test").keyup();
  });

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Test</h2>

<button id="add">Add</button>

<div class="test hidden">

  <div class="user_input2">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Pick Option</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="append">
          <td><input class="testInputs" name="test" value="1" type="checkbox">Option1</td>
          <td><input class="testInputs" name="test" value="2" type="checkbox">Option2</td>
          <td><input class="testInputs" name="test" value="3" type="checkbox">Option3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="text" id="insert" name="check[]">
    <button class="hidden" id="testbtn">Calc</button>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="paste">
</div>
```

I can't seem to get the added value removed when unchecking the box. I would need to identify the checked boxes and then remove the value based on the checked status. If anyone can help, I will be very grateful.

P.s. It should also not allow the duplication of values, as seen when you press an input check more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the `checked` checkboxes value's on the change event

```
//Added event listeners to element
$(document).on('change', '.testInputs', function () {
    //Target common ansestor
    var testContainer = $(this).closest('.test');
    //get checked checkboxes value in an array
    var checked = testContainer.find(':checked').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();

    //Target the textbox and set its value
    testContainer.find(".insert").val(checked.join(','));
});
```

Also as identifiers in HTML must be unique, You should use CSS class instead

```
<input type="text" class="insert" name="check[]">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var variable = 1
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var element = $(".test.hidden").clone(true);
    var testInputs = element.find(".testInputs").click(clickHandler);


    testInputs.attr("unique-index", variable);
    var target = element.find('.user_input2 #insert');
    target.attr("unique-identifier", variable)
    element.removeClass("hidden").appendTo(".paste:last");
    variable += 1;

  });

  function clickHandler() {
    const index = $(this).attr('unique-index')
    const targetsValue = $(`#insert[unique-identifier="${index}"]`).val();
    const combo = targetsValue ? `${targetsValue}, ${$(this).val()}` : $(this).val()
    $(`#insert[unique-identifier="${index}"]`).attr('value', combo);
  }
  
  //Added event listeners to element
  $(document).on('change', '.testInputs', function() {
    //Target common ansestor
    var testContainer = $(this).closest('.test');
    //get checked checkboxes value in an array
    var checked = testContainer.find(':checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get();

    //Target the textbox and set its value
    testContainer.find(".insert").val(checked.join(','));
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Test</h2>

<button id="add">Add</button>

<div class="test hidden">

  <div class="user_input2">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Pick Option</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="append">
          <td><input class="testInputs" name="test" value="1" type="checkbox">Option1</td>
          <td><input class="testInputs" name="test" value="2" type="checkbox">Option2</td>
          <td><input class="testInputs" name="test" value="3" type="checkbox">Option3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="text" class="insert" name="check[]">
    <button class="hidden" id="testbtn">Calc</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="paste">
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful, I admire people like you who can fluently just code and code! Thank you!